# How to integrate user accounts to an app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I have an application that I am working on, I would like to know if I could get some pointers as to where to go from here: I am looking to add the functionality for users to create accounts to log in .... i have already integrated the facebook SDK to allow facebook login, I just would like to offer a different option, other than facebook, for a simple email / password sigup.. I just dont know how to create the system (manage user accounts, passwords, etc..) I would like to be pointed in the right direction, thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Well, ive tried (and sucessfully) added facebook SDK, but its not proprietary...

Comment: You'll need a server with a database.  You'll need to have text fields.  You'll have to post to the database, check if a username/email exists, if it does, give an error.  If not, insert the username into the database.  When accessing the user, (they login) check if the user exists, and if their password is correct.  If it is, send back a cookie (or whatever you want).

Comment: Ok, so this is something that is going to be done outside of the spectrum of ios development right? (i.e.. mySql & PHP)

Comment: Yes.  However, I would advise it.  I find many users delete the app if there is only Facebook login.

Comment: Myself included, I feel like Facebook has lost credibility among a lot of its users.... thanks for the advice, I will get to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a server with a database. You'll need to have text fields. You'll have to post to the database, check if a username/email exists, if it does, give an error. If not, insert the username into the database. When accessing the user, (they login) check if the user exists, and if their password is correct. If it is, send back a cookie (or whatever you want).

It will involve more than just vanilla iOS development (e.g. PHP + MySQL, or Ruby, or MongoDB, or some other database and serve lang).